# Get number of attachments of a sent email

Tags: c++, outlook

I'm trying to get the number of attachments of an email when it's being sent (`Application.Send` event), here is the code I'm using.

```
_ApplicationPtr pApp("Outlook.Application");
_NameSpacePtr pNameSpace;
MAPIFolderPtr pOutbox;
_ItemsPtr pOutboxItems;
_MailItemPtr mi;
pNameSpace = pApp->GetNamespace(L"MAPI");
pOutbox = pNameSpace->GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox);
pOutboxItems = pOutbox->Items;
mi=pOutboxItems->GetLast();
long att_Sent=mi->GetAttachments()->Count;//Exception here
mi->Delete();
```

I always get an exception at the mi->GetAttachments->Count line (access violation). I think the mail item pointer is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Adding sanity checks would certainly be a good move; like `mi=pOutboxItems->GetLast(); assert(mi);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you retrieving the last item in the Outbox, which is not at all guaranteed to be the one being sent, and most likely you will get back null since there are no messages yet in the outbox folder when Application.ItemSend event fires?

Application.ItemSend event passes the item as an argument, why not use it?